# How to access Ruby on Rails Assets from a Host Machine

Tags: virtualbox, ruby, rails

I am running a Ruby on Rails server on an Ubuntu VirtualBox guest machine. I can access the local  server from my host machine by setting the Ubuntu network adapter to bridged. My app's hmtl is  loading OK, but the assets e.g. the images are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config/environments/development.rb` file, you need to set the config variable, asset_host, that tells the app where to load the assets. For example if your ip address of your local host is `http://10.0.2.15:3000` then

```
config.asset_host = 'http://10.0.2.15:3000'
```